# Javascript / Html Show All / Hide All Thing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hide, show

I'm trying to make a "Show All / Hide All", currently I've made it so when you click the text, it opens the image and text but I want a Show all so it will expand all divs.

Here is how it works at this moment: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ms53W/5/) .

```
    <div class="gwshowhide"><li><a class="printer">Amber Money Printer</a>
        <div class="gwinfo">Level Requirement: 1<br>
        <img src="pic.png"></div>
    </div></li>
    <div class="gwshowhide"><li><a class="printer">Moonstone Money Printer</a>
        <div class="gwinfo">Level Requirement: 5<br>
        <img src="pic1.png"></div>
    </div></li>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    $(function () {
<script>
        $('.printer').click(function () {
            $(this).siblings('.gwinfo').slideToggle('slow')
        })
    })
</script>
```

In general: I want to add a Show all / Hide all text that would open all / hide all of these at once, I also want to keep the current system so when you click one, it opens / closes it. Thank you!

Comment: Try providing the actual link to the JSFiddle

Comment: well obviously your're missing a <script></script> around your javascript code if this is exact copy of your original html file.

Comment: All fixed.. Stupid save didn't save the links. And script tags are in the actual code yes. Please respond to the actual Question, how can I make a show all / hide all to open them all at once too?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I can't think of what to try. I tried something but it never worked, any ideas?

Comment: please check this fiddle. do you need this one 
http://jsfiddle.net/Amit12x/bnY2c/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5xE8f/) to get you started. I've outlined the general gist of what you need below.

Essentially, you need two components.

**First**, HTML. Which is just another anchor to click to toggle show/hide all.

```
<a class="toggle-all">Show All</a>
```

**Second**, you need an event on that new anchor to trigger the function you have, but for ALL the options.

```
$('.toggle-all').click(function() {
    $('.printer').each(function () {
        $(this).siblings('.gwinfo').slideToggle('slow');
    });
});
```

From there, you might want to add something to toggle the text like:

```
if (open) {
    $('.toggle-all').text('Hide all');
} else { ... }
```

Bonus tip: ALWAYS put semicolons at the end of your lines in JavaScript. Even though JS will auto-insert them, it can cause difficult to debug problems as well as make IE die in some cases.

Comment: This is what I needed! Thank you a lot for taking your time!T

Answer (score 0):

```
<p class="showall">Show Hide All</p> 
<div class="gwshowhide">
    <li>
        <a class="printer">Amber Money Printer</a>
        <div class="gwinfo">Level Requirement: 1<br/>
        <img src="pic.png"/>
    </div>
</li>
</div>
<div class="gwshowhide">
    <li>
        <a class="printer">Moonstone Money Printer</a>
        <div class="gwinfo">Level Requirement: 5<br/>
        <img src="pic1.png"/>
    </div>
</li>
    </div>
```

and your jquery code would be

```
$(function () {
        $('.printer').click(function () {
            $(this).siblings('.gwinfo').slideToggle('slow');
        })
    });

$('.showall').on('click',function(){
    $('.gwinfo,.gwinfo').slideToggle('slow');

});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Amit12x/bnY2c/)

Answer (score 0):

To show/hide all use:

```
$('.gwinfo').toggle('slow');
```

Also, i believe the "gwinfo" divs are not correctly closed on the JSFiddle.